# Issue with making items menu neat

Tags: html, css

I am working on a menu with CSS where when I point on the third item in the first row of the menu, the item will be bigger and then the second row will be messy. I tried to change the margins of the items and the sizes too, but it didn't work with me. also, I tried to change the padding of the menu body and the size, but nothing worked too.

I hope there is someone who could help.
thank you in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/a1dzbg1v/1/

here are HTML code and CSS

```css
#menu {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu:hover {
  background: #f9e8b5;
}

.menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 273px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d3bd7b 0%,#ead28a 50%);
  height: 0px;
  padding: 40px 5px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-out; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s ease-out;
}

.menu-content:hover {
  height: auto;
  padding: 45px 5px 25px 5px;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s ease-out; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s ease-out;
}

.menu .menu-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.menu:hover .menu-content {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 283px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-header p{
  color: #ead28a;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.menu-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 283px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-footer p{
  color: #ead28a;
  margin: 4px;
}

.menu-item {
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, margin 2s, visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, margin 2s, visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear;
}

.menu-content .menu-item{

}

.menu-content:hover .menu-item {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

}

.menu-item:hover {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #f9e8b5;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu-item a {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d3bd7b 0%,#ead28a 50%);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #f9e8b5;
  padding: 0px;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-item a p {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transition:visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: visibility 2s, opacity 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item:hover.menu-item a p {
  font-size: 16px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-item a img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu-item:hover.menu-item a img {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu">
    <spin><img class="icon" src="#" /></spin>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <div class="menu-header">
        <p>User Menu</p>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 1</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 2</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 3</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 4</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 5</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="#" /><p>Item 6</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-footer">
        <p><?php echo date("m-d-Y :: H:i:s");?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stop messing around with properties such as padding or width and height, and use a scale transformation instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the rule about the transformation matrix is coming from; in an element inspector, it shows up in "Computed" styles, but I don't see any rule with a transform matrix in your actual CSS.

That said, I ran your code snippet and the only way I could figure out to fix your problem was to add

```
clear: left;
```

to your fourth menu-item div (the Meals one). You can do that the usual way in your stylesheet by calling nth-child or giving that element its own class name. You could also do an inline style but generally I know that's not recommended.

I'm sure there's a better way to fix this that wouldn't involve applying this to only one of your menu item divs, but it works.